# atime and mtime? Inspired by touch(1)

Tags: linux, bash

I understand that Linux system distinguishes between access and modification time of the file. How this values can be seen?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 kind of "`timestamps`":

- Access - the last time the file was read
- Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
- Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

To display this information, you can use `stat` which is part of the `coreutils`.

`stat` will show you also some more information like the device, inodes, links, etc.

Remember that this sort of information depends highly on the `filesystem` and mount options. For example if you mount a partition with the `noatime` option, no access information will be written.

so do:

```
stat filename
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l file` — show mtime.

`ls -lc file` — show ctime.

`ls -lu file` — show atime.

See [man ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls).